# Differences between railties and engines in Ruby On Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines, railtie

I read a few documents on these arguments, but I did not understand clearly what they are, what are the differences between them and if one of them fits my needs.

I need to write a piece of application which can be plugged in other application and I want to include it in other applications as a gem. Essentially I need a couple of models, one controller and no views, plus some initialization, support for configuration parameters coming from the hosting app and a generator.

Am I on the right way?

What should I read to understand how to do that?

**Update:**

A very nice article with a lot af details can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/af7e572c2dc973add221).

Essentially:

> Railtie is the core of the Rails Framework and provides several hooks to extend Rails and/or modify the initialization process.
>
> A Rails::Engine is nothing more than a Railtie with some initializers already set. And since Rails::Application and Rails::Plugin are engines, the same configuration described here can be used in all three.

Comment: I just released my first gem written as a Rails::Engine, it's available on [Github](https://github.com/fabn/google_authentication) thanks for the hint.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118905/rails-3-1-engine-vs-mountable-app/17263429

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Railtie can probably do what you describe, but it may be more desirable to use an engine.  The engine can have its own configuration and also acts like a Rails application, since it allows you to include the /app directory with controllers, views and models in the same manner as a regular Rails app.

[Read this blog for more info](http://web.archive.org/web/20130526045459/http://blog.loopedstrange.com/modest-rubyist-archive/rails-3-plugins-part1-the-big-picture)

Comment: Very nice pointer, it does explain a lot of things. Moreover, there is a link with a very interesting document which explain differences even better. I'll update my question to add that link.

Answer (score 8):

`Rails::Engine` inherits all the functionality from `Rails::Railtie` and adds some more ([`Engine < Railtie` source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L345) [docs in the source are pretty good]).

Basically, **railtie** (== your class that inherits from `Rails::Railtie`) gives you all you need to interact with Rails app processes.
And **engine** (== your class that inherits from `Rails::Engine`) is **railtie** +

- some initializers set (with help of `initializer` method): makes your **engine**'s Rails app-like folder structure loadable into the real app, so that

  > **engine** will automatically load `app/models`, `app/controllers`, `app/helpers` into your real app, load routes from `config/routes.rb`, load locales from `config/locales/*`, and load tasks from `lib/tasks/*`.

  You can see initializers set with this code:

  ```
  require 'rails/all'
  Rails::Railtie.initializers.map(&:name) #=> []  
  Rails::Engine.initializers.map(&:name)  #=> [:set_load_path, :set_autoload_paths, :add_routing_paths, :add_locales, :add_view_paths, :load_environment_config, :append_assets_path, :prepend_helpers_path, :load_config_initializers, :engines_blank_point]
  ```
- some convenience methods, such as `isolate_namespace`.

Comment: You forgot to `map`: `Rails::Engine.initializers.map(&:name)`