# Ruby on Rails User Control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to develop some kind of user control solution in Rails, so then that control can be easily added to Ruby On Rails sites.
For example, lets say, i want to create some chat user control with its own database,views,controllers, so then that chat control can be added to Ruby On Rails sites.

Is this possible? And if yes, what should i learn for that(plugins,gems?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: See my previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497834/differences-between-railties-and-engines-in-ruby-on-rails-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build an [Engine](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=rails%203%20engines).

Comment: Thanks, though it looks quite difficult to create an engine, but you pointed me to what i should learn!!