# Is Devise fully compatible with ruby on rails 3.1? It seems to be working but several files are missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I can't seem to find certain files .. e.g. files for validation (i'm aware we can override this anyway). Where is the devise controller located etc?

Would appreciate some advice on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise is an [engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497834/differences-between-railties-and-engines-in-ruby-on-rails-3), so you're going to find the actual files in the path reported by the command

```
gem which devise
```

On my system is

```
/Users/fabio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, devise is compatible with rails 3.1.
The controllers are located [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise).
The locale files are located [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/config/locales).

Devise being an engine, you don't need to have the controllers, locales and views (and even assets if there were some) in your application, they can remain in the gem.

Devise being very modular though, you can override the default controllers to add your own actions. See [How To : change the default sign in and sign out methods](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes).