# Rails 3 mountable engine routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm creating a mountable engine in ROR 3.1.3 and I have a problem with creating non-restful 
 routes.

My controller:

```
#sessions_controller.rb
module Loginout
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def abc
      raise 'aaaaaaaa'
    end
.......
```

routes:

```
#routes.rb
get '/sessions/abc'
#match '/sessions/abc', :to => 'sessions#abc'
```

> http://localhost:3000/loginout/sessions/abc

gives me an error:

> Routing Error
>
> uninitialized constant SessionsController

And while I use match instead it works fine (rises the exception). Why does it fail with get? How to fix this get?

Comment: You don't have access to the session in a mountable app.  You might want to look into a normal engine.  There is a hack to do this but then you basically convert the mountable app into a normal engine

Comment: Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118905/rails-3-1-engine-vs-mountable-app for the difference between mountable engines vs a full engine

Comment: Is there a 'smart' way for doing this?

Comment: Which and why would you choose to create a log in/out module. (Users table, maybe Credentials table, and a log in/out controller)

Comment: link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118905/rails-3-1-engine-vs-mountable-app