# Rails Engine with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, rails-engines

I'm creating standalone rails engine application which will be further added to main application, using mongoid. So, I started like this.

```
rails plugin new some_engine --mountable --skip-active-record
```

Then in the gem file:

```
gem 'mongoid', "~> 3.0.15"
```

Then I run this command for generating mongo config file:

```
some_engine\test\dummy>rails g mongoid:config
```

which generate mongoid.yml under test/dummy/config folder

Now if I generate some model it's still invoking active record

```
some_engine>rails generate scaffold post title:string
```

it gives output:

```
 invoke  active_record
 create    db/migrate/20121219170013_create_some_engine_posts.rb
...........
```

Then I change the rails file under script/rails folder as it's having:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

to

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Then if I generate something it still not invokes mongoid

```
some_engine>rails generate model post
```

Nothing happens here.

Also when I run

```
some_engine>rails generate scaffold post title:string

 invoke  resource_route.....
```

Is that I'm missing something here to use mongoid with Rails Engine?

Comment: Are you expecting a migration to be created? Mongodb doesn't require migrations.

Comment: NO, I'm just expecting to use generators as normal. As you can see it doesn't generate model when I run  rails g model command. Also when I create model manually it's not able to save the record.

Comment: What's --mountable for? My rails doesn't have that option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118905/rails-3-1-engine-vs-mountable-app   Also check.. rails plugin --help

Comment: Ah I missed the "plugin" part of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like mongoid still isn't loaded. I'm sorry, but I don't have time to reproduce. What happens if you explicitly require mongoid in the `engine.rb` file?

Comment: No problem. You might have to add require statements for anything else the engine relies on as well.

Comment: `require 'mongoid' ` in `engine.rb` worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4 if we do not need active_resource.The generated plugin app has rails modules loaded in bin/rails.

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "mongoid"
require 'rails/engine/commands'
```

Comment: I have written a quick post about this, http://fedible.org/2014/07/13/rails-engines-with-mongoid/ .