# Rails Engine can share Routes, but not Routing Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing, rails-engines

I'm trying to share routing concerns of my engine with the host application.

What I'd like to achieve is the following:

```
# MyGem/config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :commentable do
    resources :comments
  end
end

# HostApp/config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, concerns: :commentable
end
```

Which results in `No concern named commentable was found!`.

I've tested just using the resource without the concern, and I can tell that the host is inheriting my routes, just not concerns.

This could be a load order issue, if the engine routes are loaded last. Which would explain why I could still see the resources comments.

The only thing I can think of is a building a method similar to `devise_for :model`.

Something along the lines of `mygem_concerns`, I suppose.

If anyone has any other suggestions I would truly appreciate the help.

Comment: Why does your engines routes file say MyGem.application.routes.draw instead of MyGem::Engine.routes.draw?

Comment: Because you can do this as well to have full engine routes. If I put a resource or route in `mygem/config/routes.rb`, it will be accessible to the host application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118905/rails-3-1-engine-vs-mountable-app

Comment: Is this still the case in Rails 4.2? If so, that's unfortunate. I was under the impression that it had been fixed beyond the release of the concerns gem that I was using in 3.2. In 3.2 I ended up doing something like what you suggest RE devise. A method that declares the routes when called. Does the trick, but it'd be nice to be able to use the Rails Way.